# How can I skip tests in an SBT build?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an SBT 0.7.5 project and its some test cases fail.  Until all test cases are fixed, I want to skip tests to generate a JAR.  Is there any command line argument that tells SBT to skip all tests, like Maven's `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` flag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `compile`, you could use `package`. The compile tasks also runs the tests, package doesn't.

Comment: what does this answer mean?  Example?

Comment: Despite it works in several circumstances, this answer does not really answer the question. A proper answer should say how you can disable tests in a certain scope, instead of directing you to employ another task, instead of ``test``.

Answer (score 114):

I had the same problem, I'm using the [assembly plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). In this case, the solution was to modify the build file and add

```
test in assembly := {}
```

Comment: This should be the marked as the proper answer, cos it tells you how ``test`` can be made to do nothing in a certain scope.

Comment: This changes the build file though, which isn't how I would want to skip tests - the maven command line flag is a more useful version, but it appears there is no (sbt-) run-time option to skip tests.

Comment: Indeed, this can also be done at-runtime-only using the `set` keyword of sbt, like `sbt 'set test in assembly := {}' clean assembly`. See [kshakir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31737303/1885518) from [How run sbt assembly command without tests from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499444/how-run-sbt-assembly-command-without-tests-from-command-line/)

Comment: Hi, when I add this to build.sbt I get the error: error: not found: value assembly
running sbt assembly words just fine.