# How to skip tests in certain jenkins builds?

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt

My jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
 stage('Build Scala Code and Generate Dockerfile') {
   container('sbt') {
     sh "sbt -batch myapp/docker:stage"
   }
 }
```

For certain deployments [debugging] I would like to skip tests so that the build happens faster. Is there a way to do this in sbt? I am using the sbt docker plugin.

Comment: How would you identify debugging deployments?

Comment: I need to deploy to server to do the debugging. I just need to skip the testing phase so the builds deploy faster

Comment: I understand. How would the code know that you are doing a debug deployment? A parameter in Jenkins?

Comment: I am just looking to do this on one time basis. So I would just do it from `Replay` feature in Jenkins. I'm not looking to make this change for good or skip the tests based on a parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How run sbt assembly command without tests from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499444/how-run-sbt-assembly-command-without-tests-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a boolean parameter `DEBUG` to tell Jenkins, that you are doing a debug deployment, you could change your stage like this:

```groovy
stage('Build Scala Code and Generate Dockerfile') {
  container('sbt') {
    sh "sbt ${params.DEBUG ? 'set test in Test := {}' : ''} -batch myapp/docker:stage"
  }
}
```

Edit: since don't want a parameter, this might be better for you:

```groovy
stage('Build Scala Code and Generate Dockerfile') {
  container('sbt') {
    sh "sbt 'set test in Test := {}' -batch myapp/docker:stage"
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm Doesn't seem to be skipping tests

Comment: No, I tried locally too but it doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the sbt docker plugin.